# rquest.querystring cuts the value off before the & character

Tags: query-string

I've got a query string containing the following data:

`{departmentId=C&L}`

However, when I use the following code to get the data out of the query string `DepartmentName = Request["departmentId"];`

At the end the DepartmentName only contains the first letter C. So the result is: `DepartmentName=C`

So it can't find the page afterwords and returns a `404`

So what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: & is delimiter for the query string you can use it as value. you can encode it though

Comment: `&` is delimiter char for url. `C&L` should be `C%26L` (see `encodeURIComponent('C&L')`) in url string (**keys** and **values** should be encoded)

Comment: thnx guys its fixed